# Coding with Miracast in Android, is it possible to control the screen mirroring inside custom app

Tags: android, mirroring, miracast

Is it possible to code the controls to select, connect and mirror the screen of a compatible device to a TV device using Miracast from within a developed app? Or must the connection be created outside the application?

Searching for examples of WIFI DIRECT apps I have not been able to find an one that connects and mirrors a device (tablet or phone) from within the coded app.